What is the Shortcut in IntelliJ/WebStorm for selecting "const" or "var" while introducing variable?

What key on the keyboard to press here to select var or const as per the screenshot above? I couldn't find the answer on the website.
Here some more characters because StackOverflow wont let me ask the question otherwise:
HBHDBAWufbvsufbuzfbiuwefbwebiuhfniuewnfwebfiewzubfweiujfnbwiujjhn

@LazyOne Why did you cross out the filler but not delete it? Is there a software limitation?

@Zonko Because the restriction for the min post body length applies to everyone. For the current question body (after removing the "filler") it shows: "Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results."

Ok. It seems that there is no way to select the type of variable with a keyboard shortcut. But when you select one by clicking on it, this will become the new default.

From the WebStorm documentation:
In the editor, select the expression to convert into a variable and press
⌘⌥V (on MacOS) / Ctrl+Alt+V (on Windows) and select Refactor | Introduce Variable.
Further on in the dialog you should be able to select one of these.

shure but the question is how to select one of these with the keyboard

In IntelliJ IDEA you can select similar options on mac using the option key; this will underline one of the letters in the option and pressing that letter will then select that option. Idk if WebStorm has something similar.
